# Why are some apps showing their keyboard shortcuts in another language?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, language, localization

I'm using Windows 7 at work (not by choice) and while I have the OS and keyboard language set to English, it seems like some apps still display keyboard shortcuts in German (e.g., Strg+Umschalt+J). PhpStorm is one such app.

Is there a setting I might be missing? All other text in the affected apps appears in English.

Comment: This sounds like a question for your IT staff not Superuser.  The problem is you very likely have a German language pack installed on your system.

Comment: We *are* the "IT staff" ;) I just don't know the ins and outs of Windows.

Comment: First verify the only language pack you have installed is English both for Windows and PhpStorm.  After you confirm that load up your default configuration image into a virtual machine and verify the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Funny. Didn't notice it before. 
I think you have to install a language pack for English. The key-name are taken afaik from Windows itself. 
PHPStorm itself is English.. at least for my installation (also English Keyboard Layout and Windows 7).

Comment: But Windows itself *is* in English too... that's what's confusing me.

Comment: afaik is PHPStorm programmed in Java. Maybe the used Java Engine is German and the Menu entries are English fix but the key names taken from the Java Runtime Enviroment are German?

Comment: Thanks! I bet that's it. PhpStorm is indeed a Java program, and your theory would explain why only some apps exhibit this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the format setting in the Region and Language control panel. I never understood why translations are part of format in OSs. Format should be *just* that.